# access variable data from function node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this:

```
    const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
    email: 'email@email.com',
  });

  console.log(customers)
```

I want to access the `id` of the customer, so my initial thought was:

```
console.log(customer.id)
```

however, it does not work. It says undefinied. the way the customers are getting returned is like so:

```
    {
  object: 'list',
  data: [
    {
      id: 'sub_id',
      object: 'subscription',
```

so i want to access `customers.id` if possible. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you ever only get one customer returned:

```
console.log(customers.data[0].id);
```

If there are multiple:

```
for (const idData of customers.data){
    console.log(idData.id)
}
```

Make sure to check out [iterations](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

**EDIT:**

Also make sure to check out [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. i was able to successfully retrieve the id of the customer from using your code. I then tried to use it, but change the paramaters for retrieving the subscription data. ` const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
    customer: customerID
  });` then log it using this: `console.log(subscriptions.data[0].status)`. However, it returns nothing. Am i doing it wrong? not fully understanding the concepts here unfortunately lol

Comment: Maybe first try to `console.log` the value of `subscriptions` as I don't know how that object is looking. Also please check my edit for the concept of working with objects.

Comment: As you are continuing your questions in https://stackoverflow.com/q/69740745/16288497 I would love having you accept my answer here.