# retrieve status of subscription stripe node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have this:

```
 const customers = await stripe.customers.list({
    email: 'contact@Inderatech.com',
  });

  var customerID = customers.data[0].id;


  const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
    customer: customerID
  });

console.log(subscriptions)
  console.log(subscriptions.data[0].status)
```

and what it is supposed to do is retrieve the `customerid` of the subscriber, then i try to go to the next function and retrieve the `status` of the subcsription based on the customerid. This isn't working. it says 2 things.

1. it just outputs:

   { object: 'list', data: [], has_more: false, url: '/v1/subscriptions' }
2. `(node:30746) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

which i know is false, because when i just log it like so:

```
console.log(subscriptions)
```

it returns over 30 lines of the subcsribers data, including the active status. like so:

```
{
      id: 'sub_id',
      object: 'subscription',
      application_fee_percent: null,
      automatic_tax: [Object],
      billing_cycle_anchor: 1617410065,
      billing_thresholds: null,
      cancel_at: null,
      cancel_at_period_end: false,
      canceled_at: null,
      collection_method: 'charge_automatically',
      created: 1617410065,
      current_period_end: 1635899665,
      current_period_start: 1633221265,
      customer: 'cus_JEQIfxhiRu7qJh',
      days_until_due: null,
      default_payment_method: 'pm_1IbxRUIPT89VeZtCxyEA8SMu',
      default_source: null,
      default_tax_rates: [],
      discount: null,
      ended_at: null,
      items: [Object],
      latest_invoice: 'in_1JgIfuIPT89VeZtC2jsKCHRp',
      livemode: false,
      metadata: {},
      next_pending_invoice_item_invoice: null,
      pause_collection: null,
      payment_settings: [Object],
      pending_invoice_item_interval: null,
      pending_setup_intent: null,
      pending_update: null,
      plan: [Object],
      quantity: 1,
      schedule: null,
      start_date: 1617410065,
      status: 'active',
      tax_percent: null,
      transfer_data: null,
      trial_end: null,
      trial_start: null
    },
```

how can i access the status, or any other paramaters from this?

***EDIT***
to make it more clear, I will show this:

when i do this:

```
    const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
  });

  console.log(subscriptions)
```

it returns the whole big output (one showed above).

thne when i do this:

```
    const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
    customer: customerID
  });

  console.log(subscriptions)
```

it only shows this:

```
{ object: 'list', data: [], has_more: false, url: '/v1/subscriptions' }
```

and when i try to log the subscription status of the one that compares the `customerid`, i get it saying that status is not a part of the returned data.

Comment: What is the structure of the subscriptions object?

Comment: @damnedOperator just added it in above

Comment: second error from `console.log(subscriptions.data[0].status)` because there is no data field

Comment: @cmgchess the problem is that there is a status field, but not when i specify the customerid. but i need to, because there is no other way to grab a specific record for a subscirber without using the subscrption id, which i dont have. so i need to use the customer id to locate a specific record, and then find the status of that record.

Comment: is your `customerID` cus_JEQIfxhiRu7qJh

Comment: @cmgchess yes it is

Comment: `{ object: 'list', data: [], has_more: false, url: '/v1/subscriptions' }` means data is empty. is it possible that your customerID doesnt have related subscriotions

Comment: @cmgchess omg. it just clued in when you said that. I was using the inactiev subscritption email address. wow. sorry for wasting yall's time. thanks for the help

Comment: It is also worth noting that multiple Customer objects may have the same email so the current code will only grab subscriptions for the most recent customer object with that email. You may want to loop through the customers returned or write logic in your integration to make sure you only ever create one Customer object per email.

Answer (score 0):

So if the output you posted is all you got from the stripe API then the right way to access the status field would be to just use

```
console.log(subscriptions[0].status);
```

Comment: should be `(subscriptions.status)`

Comment: Beware of the comma at the end of his schema example. That indicates that the excerpt was pulled off an array.... My bets are on an array

Comment: @damnedOperator thanks for your response. I just made an edit to my post at the bottom, please see it. It explians more in depth what the issue is and what is happening. Not sure why its happening, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

That error message lines up with the output you say you are getting. If the list call does not return any Subscriptions, `subscriptions.data[0]` will be undefined so there is no object to get a `status` of.  Because your call without the `customer` filter properly returns subscriptions, the call with the filter should work as long as that customer you pass in has subscriptions that have not been cancelled (`subscriptions.list` only returns uncanceled subscriptions by default[1]).

It sounds like this may be happening because of the specific customer ID you are filtering on. If you try one of the customer IDs that you see when you list subscriptions without a filter (like `cus_JEQIfxhiRu7qJh`), does your code work? For the customer you listed in your first example, I would double check that customer’s page in your dashboard to see if they have uncanceled subscriptions that should be returned by that list call.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list